# Proving $H$ is a subgroup of $G \times G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an Abelian group. Let $H$ be the subset of $G \times G$ consisting
of all elements of the form:

$(g, g^2), g \in G$, i.e. $H = \{(g, g^2) : g \in G\}$.

Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G \times G$.

Really stuck on how to start this question, any hints or advice would be great.

Comment: To prove $H$ is a subgroup, you will need to prove that $\forall \left( g_1, g_1^2 \right), \left( g_2, g_2^2 \right) \in H, \left( g_1, g_1^2 \right) \cdot \left( g_2, g_2^2 \right)^{-1} \in H$. Here, $\cdot$ is the operation for $G \times G$ and so is the inverse relative to the operation $\cdot$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $H$ is a subgroup, you need to show $H \neq \emptyset$ and if $\alpha, \beta \in H$, then $\alpha \beta^{-1} \in H$.

Let $e$ be the identity of $G$, then $(e,e^2) \in H$. Let $\alpha=(g,g^2)$ and $\beta=(k,k^2)$ for some $g,k \in G$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\alpha\beta^{-1}&=(g,g^2)(k,k^2)^{-1}\\
&=(gk^{-1},g^2k^{-2})
\end{align*}
Now use the fact that $G$ is abelian to conclude that $g^2k^{-2}=(gk^{-1})^2$.

Comment: Great, thank you so much. So just to clarify since G is abelian we conclude that $\beta^{-1}\alpha$ yields the same result as $\alpha\beta^{-1}$, therefore getting our result of $g^2k^{-2}=(gk^{-1})^2$.

Comment: @Reety Yes. $(gk^{-1})^2=(gk^{-1})(gk^{-1})=g(k^{-1}g)k^{-1}=g(gk^{-1})k^{-1}=g^2k^{-2}$.